# Applying the chain rule correctly to $f(x,g(x))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R},\; (x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$, $g$ and $f$ continuously differentiable, $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. How to apply the chain rule on $f(x,g(x))$ correctly?

Is it $$D(f(x,g(x)))=Df(x,g(x))\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ g'(x)   \end{pmatrix}$$ or $$D(f(x,g(x)))=Df(x,g(x))\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ g'(x) & 0 \end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: $f(x,g(x))$ maps $\mathbb R $ to $\mathbb R .$ How could the answer be a vector?

Answer (score 0):

You have a map $\widetilde{g}: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ given by $\widetilde{g}(x) = (x,g(x))$. You can also call $\widetilde{f}: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, by $\widetilde{f} = f \circ \widetilde{g}$. So: $$D\widetilde{f}(x) = Df(\widetilde{g}(x))\circ D\widetilde{g}(x) = Df(x,g(x))\circ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ g'(x) \end{pmatrix},$$because $\widetilde{g}: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ means that $D\widetilde{g}(x)$ is a $2 \times 1$ matrix. In the same fashion, we must have $D\widetilde{f}(x)$ a real number, and this really happens, since $Df(x,g(x))$ is a $1 \times 2$ matrix. And we know that a $1 \times 2$ matrix times a $2 \times 1$ matrix gives a real number ($1 \times 1$ matrix).

Comment: why $Df(x,g(x))$ is 1x2 matrix? which are the two element of the vector? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider the functions $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ you have and the function $G:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ given by $G(x)=(x,g(x))$.
The derivative (gradient) of $G$ is $(1,g'(x))$ and the function you want to differentiate is $f\circ G$.
Can you take it from here?